# What to do if the datagridview is transperent and I cannot click at that because the cursor aims at the desktop or at the from behind?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am just a student so that's very untypical issue for me. I'm using one BindingSource and I'm trying to:

1. create some columns and the names of the last
2. create one row of data

My code is here:

```
private void MainCore_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvTowns.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(); 
        column.DataPropertyName = "Name";
        column.Name = "Назва"; gvTowns.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(); 
        column.DataPropertyName = "Country"; 
        column.Name = "Країна"; 
        gvTowns.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(); 
        column.DataPropertyName = "Region"; 
        column.Name = "Регіон"; 
        gvTowns.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(); 
        column.DataPropertyName = "Population"; 
        column.Name = "Мешканців"; 
        gvTowns.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(); 
        column.DataPropertyName = "YearIncome"; 
        column.Name = "Річн. дохід"; 
        gvTowns.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(); 
        column.DataPropertyName = "Square"; 
        column.Name = "Площа"; column.Width = 80;
        gvTowns.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(); 
        column.DataPropertyName = "HasPort"; 
        column.Name = "Порт"; column.Width = 60;
        gvTowns.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(); 
        column.DataPropertyName = "HasAirport";
        column.Name = "Аеропорт"; column.Width = 60;
        gvTowns.Columns.Add(column);

        bindSrcTowns.Add(new Seeking_of_the_city("Львів", "Україна", "Львівська обл.", 800000, 2000000, 400, false, true));


    }
```

MainCore is the name of the form. The name of the datagridview is gvTowns.

So I showcase the photo of the form:

[image]

As you can see, the row is here, but unvisible. And I don't know what to do with that. Is this problem in the properties? If that's true, in which?

Comment: Did you check/set The BackColor to Color.Transparent?

Comment: BackgroundColor -> AppWorkspace

Comment: I don't use transparent color.

Comment: I cannot guess the resolve. What property have I chnage?

Comment: It should be either that or maybe setting TransparencyKey for the form..

Comment: There was a white color. And it didn't work. But now I have opted DarkGrey. And it would work perfectly if it show the row. But the row is empty. There's no data there.

Comment: So I can click at the DataGridView and I know that I click at the right form.

Comment: And the DataGridView isn't transparent now. I don't know what wrong with that white color is.

Comment: Did you check the TransparencyKey  ??

Comment: The transparency key was white. I said, I've changed the color into DarkGrey. And the datagridview has become visible. But the row isn't visible. I don't see the data of this row. Perhaps, the font color is white. I don't know where to search this property. But the situation is better.

Comment: _The transparency key was white_ This is a __mistake__! Change it back to its default (None). For this click into the field and delete all the numbers. The rectangle will still look white but the color is gone. Now you can use all colors including white in all your controls..!